# Replace random generated resource name in the xml list in Bash to be useful Jenkins grrovy pipeline

Tags: xml, bash, jenkins-pipeline

I have an xml file to find and replace a line where there is url which is linked to where the Resource name =  "java/RulesPlugin"

The issue is that sometimes the <Resource name="java/RulesPlugin" might be out of sequence and not in the first line. I was only able to find the example.co.uk if the  Resource name =  "java/RulesPlugin" is first in the list but I need to be able to filter where the url is with <Resource name="java/RulesPlugin" no matter the location or sequence in that file.

script :

```
grep -oPm1 '(?<=url="jdbc:postgresql://)[^<]+' <  test.xml | sed -r 's/^.{0}//' | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' |   cut -d: -f1
varurl=`grep -oPm1 '(?<=url="jdbc:postgresql://)[^<]+' <  test.xml | sed -r 's/^.{0}//' | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' |   cut -d: -f1`
echo "${varurl}"        
sed -i -e "0,/$varurl/ s/$varurl/newstring-replace.co.uk/g" test.xml
```

If the xml content with  <Resource name="java/RulesPlugin" is not the first in the list but is down in the middle randomly. How can I use bash to get this same result?

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    
    <Context>
    <Resource name="java/RulesPlugin"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://example.co.uk:5000/sandbox"
          user="xxxx"
          token="xxxxx"
          maxActive="100" 
          maxIdle="30" 
          maxWait="10000"
    
      />
      
      <Resource name="java/Reports"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://example.co.uk:5000/sandbox"
          user="xxxx"
          token="xxxxx"
          
     />
      <Resource name="java/Balancer"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://example.co.uk:5000/sandbox"
          user="xxxx"
          token="xxxxx"
    
     />
```

UPDATE: Thanks for all the answers, some do work on the local unix, but  I really need xml tool to work with Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Use an XML-aware tool to process XML.

Comment: how would I use this, is that the only possibility. Is it not possible to use the sed to filter and get what you want. The problem is that am still going to run this script in jenkins pipeline

Comment: [Obligatory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/26428)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you though parsing `xml` with `sed` is not a robust method.

```
sed '/Resource name="java\/RulesPlugin"/,/\/>[[:blank:]]*$/{
     /\(.*url="jdbc:postgresql:\/\/\)[^:/]*/s//\1newstring-replace.co.uk/
}' test.xml
```

Comment: This one looks like what I can use in the pipeline. But there is limitation. It is outputting all the test.xml file. It works though. Can it be possible to just silently replace without showing it.

Comment: It is also reverting back to original url

Comment: Got it now I added -i -e

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `xmllint` (present on most distros) as below. New value must be set on `url` variable

```
url="jdbc://asdasdas" echo -e "cd /Context/Resource[@name='java/RulesPlugin']/@url\nset $url\nsave\nbye") |  xmllint --shell tmp.xml
/ > cd /Context/Resource[@name='java/RulesPlugin']/@url
url > set jdbc://asdasdas
url > save
url > bye
```

As the output shows, 4 commands were pass to `xmllint --shell`

```
/ > cd /Context/Resource[@name='java/RulesPlugin']/@url
url > set jdbc://asdasdas
url > save
url > bye
```

Alternatively and assuming XML format is in the provided format regardless of attributes order, it could be done with awk as

```
url='url="jdbc:postgresql://example.com:7777/sandbox"'
gawk -v url="$url" '
    BEGIN{RS="[/]>\n"; FS="\n"; OFS="\n"}
    {
        if (NR==1 && $0 ~ /java[/]RulesPlugin/){
            for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                if($i ~ /url=/) $i = url
            }
            print $0 "/>"
        } else {
            print $0 "/>"
        }
}' tmp.xml
```

And with `sed` as

```
tr -d '\n' < tmp.xml | sed -re 's/^(.*Resource name="java\/RulesPlugin" [^>]+  url=")([^=" ]+)(" [^>]+ *[/]>.*)/\1NEWURL\3/'
```

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer to use sed instead as this is not just bash and will make use of this in Jenkins pipeline. I want something along the line of using grep or sed

Comment: @user5820327 provided option with awk and sed.

Answer (score 0):

[Please don't use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) [inappropriate tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747) [to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105)! An XML-parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) would be more suited:

```
$ xidel -s test.xml -e '
  x:replace-nodes(
    Context/Resource[@name="java/RulesPlugin"]/@url,
    attribute url {"newstring-replace.co.uk"}
  )
' --output-format=xml --output-node-indent
```